# Is it possible to have own push notification server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'd like to ask if is possible to have own push notifciation server without connecting to google or etc for web push in chrome or safari, the main problem is I want to use push notification in intranet without connection to internet

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: would you help with some library ?

Comment: Look into SignalR

Comment: yes, I searched and face to pushsharp, but it uses google fcm

Comment: This has been asked here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538371/create-a-web-push-notification-service-like-onesignal

Answer (score 3):

Everyone is answering different facets of "push notifications" and "servers", but they're missing the context of what you're actually asking. Assuming you're talking about push notifications sent to either mobile devices or to web clients via WebPush, the answer is: no.

The servers are run by the vendors: Apple/Google in the case of mobile notifications and Apple/Mozilla/Google (Safari, Firefox, and Chrome, respectively) in the case of WebPush. You can't run your own. There's a trust relationship that needs to be established between the push server and the client, which can only be provided by the vendor of that client (mobile platform/web browser).

Comment: You are just assuming that OP asked about having a special server when being the submitter of push notifications. He never states that. This question would also apply if I want to have my own server for receiving push notifications in chromium from other websites, not when I am the website submitting the notification.